# rails activerecord query joins vs includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, include

I have the following models

Video belongs_to :customer
Message belongs to :video, :customer, has_many :recipients through :recipient_list
RecipientList belongs_to :recipient, :message
VideoActivity belongs_to :video, :message, :recipient

I need to do a query on a customer's last 100 recipient lists that gets values from column's of the message it's tied to, the video that's tied to that message, and the video activity that's tied to that message and the recipient.

I currently have this ugly query but was wondering how the best way to speed it up is. Would it be better to start with videos and then .includes messages, video_activities, and recipient lists? It takes really long for a user who has a lot of videos.

```
@videos = RecipientList.select("recipient_lists.*,
                                  COALESCE(sum(video_activities.duration_in_seconds),0) AS video_watched_duration_in_seconds,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.video_watched_count),0) AS video_views,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.response_count),0) AS responses,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.email_opened_count),0) AS email_opens,
                                  CASE WHEN COUNT(video_activities.id) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_activity,
                                  MAX(video_activities.updated_at) AS last_activity,
                                  MAX(video_activities.email_opened_at) AS last_opened,
                                  MAX(video_activities.video_watched_at) AS last_watched,
                                  MAX(video_activities.responded_at) AS last_responded")
                     .joins("LEFT JOIN messages ON 52 = messages.customer_id
                             LEFT JOIN videos ON (messages.video_id = videos.id AND videos.template = false)
                             LEFT JOIN video_activities ON (videos.id = video_activities.video_id AND messages.id = video_activities.message_id AND recipient_lists.recipient_id = video_activities.recipient_id)")
                     .group("recipient_lists.id")
                     .where("messages.customer_id = 52")
                     .order("recipient_lists.created_at DESC")
                     .limit(100)
                     .load
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, would it be faster to do it this way?

```
RecipientList.limit(100).order("recipient_lists.created_at DESC").each do |recipient|
  @message = Message.find(recipient.message_id)
  @video = Video.find(@message.video_id)
  @video_activity = @video.video_activities.where(user_id: recipient.id)
end
```